# JavaScript + event propagation

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an input box that successfully toggles a hidden div.  However, I also want the div to hide when the user clicks anything other than the div itself.  How might I do this?

**html**

```
<input id="inputID" type="text" readonly />
<div id="divID"></div>
```

**js**

```
var divObj = document.getElementById('divID');
var inputObj = document.getElementById('inputID');

inputObj.addEventListener('click', toggleDiv, false);
function toggleDiv(){
    divObj.style.display = (divObj.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none'; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an event listener on `document.body` element and check if the event originated from an element inside your div and if not hide it. You can ease this job up a bit by not checking the origin but simply preventing click events from inside your div from bubbling up by calling `.stopPropagation()` on the event object.

```
divObj.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}, false);
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    divObj.style.display = 'none';
}, false);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/D7YnS/

Comment: Can you post an example of what that might look like?  Sorry, kind of a js noob.

Comment: Oh, you have to stop the propagation of the `inputObj` click event, too. Then it works.

Comment: Excellent! I just came to that conclusion as well! Thanks for the help, the js event model just became a bit more clear to me now.

Comment: By the way, this won't work in old IE versions (they don't know `addEventListener`). If you need to support these, consider using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

ThiefMaster's approach works but has a small problem to consider if you have multiple places that need to do the same thing. Say you needed to do the same thing with two separate divs, then calling `e.stopPropagation()` would cause the div1 not to be hidden when clicking div2

Example

```
div1.addEventListeners('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
}, false);
div2.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}, false);
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    div1.style.display = 'none';
    div2.style.display = 'none';
}, false);
```

Therefore, a safer alternative is (I'll use jQuery for simplicity) http://jsfiddle.net/qzMnj/1/

```
$(function() {
    function hideWhenClickOutside(element) {
      $(document).click(function(e){
        if ( !element.contains(e.target)) {
            $(element).hide();
        }
      });
    }

    hideWhenClickOutside(document.getElementById('div1'));    
    hideWhenClickOutside(document.getElementById('div2'));
})
```

My point is that calling `stopPropagation()` can have unwanted side-effects, if you don't have to do it, it's better not to, unless you're sure no-one will ever care about that click.

Comment: @OmShankar Your comment about my answer should be under my answer, not under your own answer. In any case, I'm not using `$.contains` from jQuery, I'm using `Node.contains`. Even if I were, there's a clear disclaimer that I'm using jQuery for simplicity, I'm not going to address browser compatibility issues when the question is not about browser compatibility. Your example uses addEventListener which is not supported in older IE versions, it's the same thing, showing the simplest code to address the problem at hand

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if this works

1. call your normal listener to hide the div
2. add an additional listener to the body to hide your div if not hidden
3. add a listener to the div itself to stop the event (2. above)

   - this is known as [Event Propagation](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/eventbubbling.htm)
   - you click on the div, which eventually is a click on the body
   - you don't want to call 2. when u click inside the div

Also, note that the code above (yours) and below (mine) is not cross-browser (addEventListener doesn't work in IE8 and less)
Hoping that you are ignoring this, here goes the HTML with JS

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lab</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #divID {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top: 85px;
            border: 1px solid #020202;

            // Unnecessary stuff
            -moz-border-radius:     2px;
            -webkit-border-radius:  2px;

            -moz-box-shadow:    0 0 8px #565656;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #565656;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="inputID" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
    <div id="divID"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var divObj = document.getElementById('divID'),
        inputObj = document.getElementById('inputID');

    inputObj.addEventListener('click', toggleDiv, false);
    document.body.addEventListener('click', docClick, false);
    divObj.addEventListener('click', divClick, false);

    function divClick(e) {
        // if you click any element inside the div
        // when the click reaches the div, stop going above
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

    function docClick(e){
        if (divObj.style.display !== 'none') {
            divObj.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    function toggleDiv(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        divObj.style.display = (divObj.style.display === 'none') ? 'block' : 'none'; 
    }

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Yup, by the time he edited his comment, I had written a lot of my answer - so could not help not posting it. 

By the way, your solution works for only 2 divs, and comes back to ur own question of "What if there were 3 divs". 

I changed ur JS fiddle to add <div id='div3'> Div 3</div>, 
and it failed

Comment: @JuanMendes, additionally, you are using `contains()` which brings in jQuery dependability, to cope which, u might have to write ur additional function

Comment: I don't know what you tried, but when I add a third div and I call `hideWhenClickOutside(div3)` it does work http://jsfiddle.net/qzMnj/3/

Comment: @JuanMendes you are not getting the point. As per your solution, when you say "but when I add a third div" you have to call `hideWhenClickOutside` again. Thats the glitch. For 100 `div`s you would call that 100 times... ?

Comment: Not a glitch dude, you only have to call the function once for each div. In your example you have to call three functions and everything is hardcoded , so you'd have to change the body of the function "call function multiple time" is much better than "change the body of the function adding a line that deals with each div" when adding new elements. My answer is generalized, yours is specialized.

Comment: @JuanMendes, Hey, it seems looking at the words of ur comment, as if u were saying my point to urself. Anyways, I only wanted to pointed out that your fiddle was having a very traditional, non-efficient, repetitive approach. Sorry to have used the word "glitch". But you see, the very idea of your function being called for every div is "non-efficient". You should have ONE function that deals with any unwanted click outside.

Comment: @JuanMendes, So your statement - "My answer is generalized, yours is specialized" actually comes from me to you.

Comment: You make very little sense, just write out the code required to handle 3 divs using my style and your style. My style is repetition of calling one function, passing it different arguments, your style requires hardcoding each div inside the function

Comment: @JuanMendes, Nope, thats wrong. Wondering on your grasping skills, I would like to explain once more: **1. your approach** - as the no. of div increases, you go back and modify your function. OR you call your function again with new params. - inefficient and not as per **[DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)** principles. **2. My approach** - has a function that manages any click outside the required div. Even when the no. of divs increase, they are all outside. you never have to go back to your code - **efficient**.  
I think it can't get simpler than this. Cheers